# how to group common elements in list depending on same keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following data

Table headers: name , type, version,check

```
        [["FoxService","XML","1.0",null],
        ["JsonRest","JSON","1.0",null],
        ["JsonTest","JSON","1.0",null],
        ["JsonTest","JSON","2.0",null],
        ["RDBMSIntegration","Database","1.0",null],
        ["SalesforceService","None","1.0",null],
        ["SAPIntegration","JSON","1.0",null],
        ["SAPIntegration","JSON","2.0",null],
        ["SAPIntegration","JSON","3.0",null],
        ["SFTest","XML","1.0",null]]
```

which i am getting from hibernate(from DB) to angularjs, but not able to show in UI, as i need to show versions in list box. i am not able to map to ng-rpeate or ng-options , if data is in follwoing format.

```
        [["FoxService","XML",[1.0],null],
        ["JsonRest","JSON",[1.0],null],
        ["JsonTest","JSON",[1.0,2.0],null],
        ["RDBMSIntegration","Database",[1.0],null],
        ["SalesforceService","None",[1.0],null],
        ["SAPIntegration","JSON",[1.0,2.0,3.0],null],
        ["SFTest","XML",[1.0],null]         ]
```

I can show on UI easily , but i have tried with group_concat and some other things but all thoose are DB specfic , i didnt get any solution which works for all DB's . If i tried on angularjs side multiple times i need to iterate the array to make requried format.
Hope i explained well.
can someone help me to find better solution.
It can be anything SQL query or Hibernate or angularjs or plain JS or in java(last option) ..

Thank you

Comment: Why is this tagged SQL?  What database are you using?  What does the table look like?

Comment: it is for all DBS same query should  work for all dbs.
APP(appId(pk), appName,Type, Version,check).

i will retrive only appName,Type, Version,check 
And same app name can have multiple versions

Answer (score 0):

Array iteration is difficult to do in ng-repeat. Also if we iterate, how do you bind the data without any key.

Convert the array to an object and then try it in an ng-repeat.